# How to reinitialize QMessageBox for reuse

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

I have some code whereby I need to create 2 occurrences of a QMessageBox in C++.
I would like to use the same declaration for both.

How can I reinitialize the original declare to avoid seeing the additional "Proceed" button on the second QMessageBox?  I do not want to use the removeButton method.

Example logic:

```
QMessageBox mb;
mb.setText("Shall we proceed?");
QAbstractButton *btn = mb.addButton(trUtf8("Proceed"), QMessageBox::YesRole);
int response = mb.exec();

if (response == QMessageBox::Cancel) 
    return;

.
.
.

mb.setText("I don't want to see a Proceed button here");
response = mb.exec();

if (response == QMessageBox::Cancel)
    return;
```

Comment: If it's only about _the same declaration for both_, create `QMessageBox *mb = new QMessageBox()` instead and then when you need reinitialize - delete and create `new QMessageBox`

Comment: For such simple usage, why not using static API?

Comment: Couldn't you just delete `btn`?